Can we save multiple changes at once using JaVers library?
I'm using the JaVers library. It seems I cannot save multiple changes at once.
Is there a way to do so? If no then is there a possibility to add it?
Maybe it is due to the diff being made with every change that is preventing that. If that is so, is it possible to disable diff capabilities and only store new versions of entities, and save them in batch?

Currently, JaVers does not support batching multiple changes in one go because it computes a diff each time an object is committed.
Also you can't disable diffing altogether because JaVers inherently relies on diffs to track object changes.
